# Failed to read marionette port(Selenium-py+Ubuntu+Geckodriver)

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, marionette, geckodriver

Im running a tiny script(See below).
Every time I run it I get: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port`
I'm on Ubuntu 22, running Selenium 4, using Selenium-py. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

def _make_options() -> webdriver.FirefoxOptions:
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=0")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--single-process")
    return options

def _initialize_geckodriver() -> webdriver.Firefox:
    options = _make_options()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
        service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
        ,options=options,
    )
    return driver


_initialize_geckodriver()
```